# -[MyClassName copyWithZone:] unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, crash, copy

My application crashed with the reason:

> -[MyClassName copyWithZone:]  unrecognized selector sent to instance

I have two classes. Let's say Class1 and Class2.

Class1 looks like:

#### Class1.h

```
@interface Class1 : NSObject {
    NSString *imagemd5CheckSum;
    UIImage *image;
    NSData *fileChunkData;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy)NSString *imagemd5CheckSum;
@property (nonatomic, copy)UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic, copy)NSData *fileChunkData;

@end
```

#### Class1.m

```
@implementation Class1

@synthesize image;
@synthesize fileChunkData;
@synthesize imagemd5CheckSum;

-(id) init{
    [self setImage:nil];
    [self setFileChunkData:nil];
    [self setImagemd5CheckSum:@""];

    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [imagemd5CheckSum release];
    [image release];
    [fileChunkData release];

    fileChunkData = nil;
    imagemd5CheckSum = nil;
    image = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

**

> Class2 looks like

**

#### Class2.h

---

```
#import "Class2.h"
@interface Class2 : NSObject {
    Class1 *obj1;
    Class1 *obj2;
    Class1 *obj3;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy)Class1 *obj1;
@property (nonatomic, copy)Class1 *obj2;
@property (nonatomic, copy)Class1 *obj3;

@end
```

#### Class2.m

---

```
@implementation Class2

@synthesize obj1,obj2,obj3;

-(id) init{
    [self setObj1:nil];
    [self setObj2:nil];
    [self setObj3:nil];

    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [obj1 release];
    [obj2 release];
    [obj3 release];

    obj1 = nil;
    obj2 = nil;
    obj3 = nil;

    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

#### Crashed Situation

```
Class2 *class2 = [[Class2 alloc] init];

Class1 *class1 = [[Class1 alloc] init];

[class1 setImagemd5CheckSum:@"this is md5"];
[class1 setImage:myimage];
[class1 setFileChunkData:myData];

[class2 setObj1:class1]; // This line is crashed..
```

...

When I called `[class2 setObj1:class1];`, the application crashed with reason:

> -[Class1 copyWithZone:]  unrecognized selector sent to instance

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Your `-setObj1:` method is declared as `copy`, so it calls `-copy` on your `Class1` object. `-copy` just calls `-copyWithZone:nil`. So you either need to implement the `NSCopying` protocol (which means implementing `-copyWithZone:`), or change your property from `copy` to `retain`.

Answer (score 53):

To make your class respond to `copyWithZone:`, you have to implement the `NSCopying` protocol in your class. And you must override the `copyWithZone:` method.

For example:

First you have to implement the NSCopying protocol in your interface declaration.

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject <NSCopying>
```

Then override the `copyWithZone` method like,

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
    id copy = [[[self class] alloc] init];

    if (copy)
    {
        // Copy NSObject subclasses
        [copy setVendorID:[[self.vendorID copyWithZone:zone] autorelease]];
        [copy setAvailableCars:[[self.availableCars copyWithZone:zone] autorelease]];

        // Set primitives
        [copy setAtAirport:self.atAirport];
    }

    return copy;
}
```

I am glad if this helps you.

([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089238/implementing-nscopying))

Comment: i think the fact that the zone argument is [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7934142/why-zone-is-allway-nil-while-implementing-nscopying) must be mentioned in this discussion

Comment: hey man.. did you copy your code from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4089372/766570) answer? what is this airport and car stuff all about?

Comment: Look at the added reference. You will find out where airport and car stuff's all about.