# Xcode - presentViewController NSInvalidArgumentException: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So I'm trying to open a view within an app from a button press and I'm shown the following error:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationBar copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e56aa10'
```

The action for the button press is:

```
-(IBAction)launchDirections:(id)sender
{
@autoreleasepool {

if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]){



        if([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied
            || [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined
            || [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted   ){

            UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App Permission Denied"
                                           message:@"To re-enable, please go to Settings and turn on Location Service for this app."
                                          delegate:nil
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                 otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }else{
            NSLog(@"Location Services Enabled");
            ontracDirectionsMapViewController *directions = [[ontracDirectionsMapViewController alloc] init];
            directions.start = userLocation;
            directions.end =selectedPointLocation;

            //[self presentViewController:directions animated:NO completion:nil];
            //[self.navigationController pushViewController:directions animated:YES];

            [ self presentViewController : directions animated : YES completion : ^ {

                NSLog ( @ "hello" );

            }];
        }

    }
}
}
```

Additionally I have tried the two lines you can see that have been commented out:

```
//[self presentViewController:directions animated:NO completion:nil];
//[self.navigationController pushViewController:directions animated:YES];
```

These don't make any difference unfortunately. I'm new to IOS development and not sure where to go from here.

Additionally there is a method elsewhere in the app called `copyWithZone` but even if i remove this entirely I still get the error with the reference.

```
-(id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
ontracTableMasterViewController *copy = [[ontracTableMasterViewController alloc] init];
copy.cookieValue = self.cookieValue;
copy.dataObject = self.dataObject;

return copy;
}
```

Comment: `ontracDirectionsMapViewController` is on storyboard?

Comment: @Lion Yes it is, i think

Comment: One answer is there. this is seems to right. do like that.

Comment: AFAIK: the `copyWithZone` is a protocol method for [copying]( https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/) i.e. you have a property which is something like this `@property ( someOther attributes, copy)`...But you can't just say that, the object that you intend to copy must follow/conform/adapt `NSCopying` protocol, if not it will give you such an error. See [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4089238/implementing-nscopying) as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [-\[MyClassName copyWithZone:\] unrecognized selector sent to instance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391835/myclassname-copywithzone-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I lucked into an answer! What I did was change the following line `@property (copy, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *directionsNavigationBar;` in `ontracMapViewController.h` to `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UINavigationBar *directionsNavigationBar;`

This then produce the following error, `preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation must return a supported interface orientation!` which I solved by adding the code below:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
   return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
   return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Like i said in the question I'm new to IOS dev so not sure what was happening in the first place but this seems to be working fine now. Thanks to everyone for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using storyboards, set the storyboard identifier to your `ontracTableMasterViewController` and instantiate it as follows:

```
    ontracTableMasterViewController *oVC = (ontracTableMasterViewController *)[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_IDENTIFIER"];
    oVC.start = userLocation;
    oVC.end = selectedPointLocation;
    [self presentViewController:oVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Please check the attached image to set YOUR_IDENTIFIER in storyboard. 
Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: I don't have an option to set the bundle ID :/

Comment: Hello @jampez77 what are you using? storyboard or .xib or creating UI  purely programatically?